# Unable to call cloudwatch putMetricData in nodejs lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, async-await, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to use putmetric method to push some logs from my code,Everything is getting executed except this part **cw.putMetricData** and my requirement is the handler should be async.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  customNameSpace();
  return "Done";
}

async function customNameSpace() {
  const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
  AWS.config.update({
      region: 'us-east-1'
  });

  var cw = new AWS.CloudWatch({
      apiVersion: '2010-08-01'
  });

  var params = {
      MetricData: [{
          MetricName: 'test-error-lambda4',
          Dimensions: [{
              Name: 'Error-Code-lambda4',
              /* required */
              Value: '404' /* required */
          }, {
              Name: 'Message',
              /*required */
              Value: 'Not-found' /* required */
          }],
          Unit: 'None',
          Value: 1.0
      }, ],
      Namespace: 'test_order_4xx'
  };
    let res = await cw.putMetricData(params, function(err, data) {
        console.log("callback function");
        if (res.err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
            console.log("Success", JSON.stringify(data));
        }
        console.log("inside putMetricData ");
    });
    console.log("After putMetricData ");
  return "the result";
};
```

Comment: Does your Lambda function have the necessary rights to call CloudWatch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems with your code

- You are missing the `await` keyword before the `customNameSpace()` call.
- When you make the `putMetricData()` call, you are not actually waiting for the callback function to complete.

You can go through [this article](https://sarthakj178.com/handling-nodejs-promises-in-aws-lambda/) to understand handling of Node JS Promises in AWS Lambda.

Following is your code with the fixes and the expected output.

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    await customNameSpace(); // Added await here
    return 'Done';
};

async function customNameSpace() {
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({
        region: 'us-east-1'
    });

    var cw = new AWS.CloudWatch({
        apiVersion: '2010-08-01'
    });

    var params = {
        MetricData: [
            {
                MetricName: 'test-error-lambda4',
                Dimensions: [
                    {
                        Name: 'Error-Code-lambda4',
                        /* required */
                        Value: '404' /* required */
                    },
                    {
                        Name: 'Message',
                        /*required */
                        Value: 'Not-found' /* required */
                    }
                ],
                Unit: 'None',
                Value: 1.0
            }
        ],
        Namespace: 'test_order_4xx'
    };
    let res = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // Wrapped the putMetricData call in a new Promise object.
        cw.putMetricData(params, function(err, data) {
            console.log('callback function');
            if (res.err) {
                console.log('Error', err);
                reject(err); // Reject the promise
            } else {
                console.log('Success', JSON.stringify(data));
                resolve(data); // Resolve the promise
            }
            console.log('inside putMetricData ');
        });
    });
    await res; // Wait for the promise to succeed/fail.
    console.log('After putMetricData ');
    return 'the result';
}
```

**Output**:

```
START RequestId: ed8197e9-fa33-1e66-a549-4da598ab4f50 Version: $LATEST
2019-12-31T12:25:26.098Z        ed8197e9-fa33-1e66-a549-4da598ab4f50    callback function
2019-12-31T12:25:26.099Z        ed8197e9-fa33-1e66-a549-4da598ab4f50    Success {"ResponseMetadata":{"RequestId":"9d633f18-2def-435a-91c5-a82a091f16d3"}}
2019-12-31T12:25:26.099Z        ed8197e9-fa33-1e66-a549-4da598ab4f50    inside putMetricData 
2019-12-31T12:25:26.100Z        ed8197e9-fa33-1e66-a549-4da598ab4f50    After putMetricData 
END RequestId: ed8197e9-fa33-1e66-a549-4da598ab4f50
REPORT RequestId: ed8197e9-fa33-1e66-a549-4da598ab4f50  Init Duration: 169.14 ms        Duration: 1278.90 ms    Billed Duration: 1300 ms        Memory Size: 128 MB       Max Memory Used: 52 MB

"Done"
```

Comment: Wow! this worked!! you saved lot of time for me thank much,I'm new to nodejs, there  is some complexity in understanding async concept in nodejs.

Answer (score 2):

I've only learned async/await and not really Promises and callbacks, so I can't say this 100% for sure, but there is one definite issue and another possible issue in your code.

The definite issue:

> ```
> exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
>   customNameSpace();
>   return "Done";
> }
>
> async function customNameSpace() {
> ```

An async function returns a promise. Therefore the line `customNameSpace();` simply executes a function which returns a promise and does not wait for it to resolve. You need to do `await customNameSpace();` in order to wait for the `customNameSpace()` function to execute fully.

The possible issue:

> ```
> let res = await cw.putMetricData(params, function(err, data) {
>     console.log("callback function");
>     if (res.err) {
>         console.log("Error", err);
>     } else {
>         console.log("Success", JSON.stringify(data));
>     }
>     console.log("inside putMetricData ");
> });
> ```

You're mixing await with callbacks. I don't know for sure it won't work, it might, so try changing the thing mentioned above first. In any case there's a much cleaner way to do this. All(?) AWS SDK functions return an `AWS.Request` type, and that type has a `promise()` method which returns a promise which can be awaited. Although their documentation always shows callbacks (and note, never awaiting the result), I always await the promise without any callback. So the above can be rewritten as:

```
try {
    let res = await cw.putMetricData(params).promise();
    console.log("Success", JSON.stringify(res.data));
) catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
}
return "the result";
```

Comment: Yes as you mentioned those are the two issues.